# Clustering trends across categories: which one to use?

Tags: clustering, data-mining

I have a dataset with daily temperatures for every country in 4 seasons: Spring, Summer, Fall, and Winter.

I wish to group(cluster) countries with similar temperature trends across the 4 seasons. I am aware of basic clustering techniques, but clustering across categories seems new. Is there a package or any previous work on the lines of clustering data trends? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You say "trends".  Do you mean levels, or seasonal changes or something else, or changes over years.  Clustering typically involves some concept of distance (you want "close" observations to be clustered together), and how you measure that distance needs to come from specific knowledge rather than hoping some model will do it for you

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. Trends refer to changes over seasons.  I kinda want to have clusters where countries per season are close. Can't think of a straightforward way or a statistical test to do this.

Comment: It is still not clear enough. "Trends across seasons" - what does it mean? The curve shape of the 4 values (the means)? What is about trends within a season (30 values per season) - will you use this information?